# Lightning DatePicker Displaying Outside of Modal Pop-up Form

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, calendar, modal, date-picker

I have a modal form appearing on a button click. Basically just setting the flag to true and the modal is rendered (it's always on the page). The modal contains multiple fields, one of which is the lightning-input date field.
The lightning-datepicker that appears after a user clicks on the date field goes outside of the modal form, and this is a huge issue.
I've solved that by adding the following:

---

```
.slds-modal__content {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

---

Now a *scroll* appears and a user can scroll down and pick the correct date. I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve this. Without using a scroll? Does anybody have some solutions?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scroll, use overflow CSS property, which will show Calendar on the top on modal component.[image]

And if you want to have Scrollable , then the Modal body tag should have scroll class - "modal_content_scroll"

Comment: I did use the overflow property but then the calendar gets cut by the end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you roll your own modal lwc?  Maybe try [james simone's](https://github.com/jamessimone/lwc-modal)?  Not sure if it will fix your issue but I know him and a bunch of other contributors thought through a whole bunch of scenarios.